# How to write on a position absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm begginer on HTML/CSS and I don't understand how to write on a block I create.

I have to do a page with different tags like <button> ... but I don't understand how to write into a block like the first picture. All i have to do is to do a copy of the picture.

[here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7GlN.png)

So to do the work i define differents <div> and i create differents block with a colours. After i have to write something like 'Connexion' or create a button, create a section for the connexion and password but i can not do it. If someone can help to understand it will be very good please.

Thanks.

My HTML and CSS code :

```css
header {

        text-align: center;
        background-color:#0033A0;

        position: absolute;
        top:0%;
        left:0%;
        right:0%;
        bottom:78%;

        z-index:1;
        


    }

        

    nav {
        text-align:center;
        background-color:black;
        color:white;

        position: absolute;
        top:17%;
        left:0%;
        right:0%;
        bottom:79%;
        padding:8px;

        z-index:2;
    }


    footer {
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#0033A0;
        color:white;

        position: absolute;
        top:93%;
        left:0%;
        right:0%;
        bottom:0%;

        padding:23px;


    }

    #Contour {

        background-color:gray;
        color:gray;

        position: absolute;
        top:24%;
        left:2%;
        right:2%;
        bottom:10%; 
        
        z-index:1;
        padding:15px;

    }

        
    #Contour2 {
        
        background-color:green;
        
        position: absolute;
        top:26%;
        left:4%;
        right:4%;
        bottom:12%; 

        margin:top:70%;
        
        z-index:2;
        padding:15px;

    }

    #Contour3 {

        background-color:blue   ;
        
        position: absolute;
        top:70%;
        left:6%;
        right:6%;
        bottom:15%; 
        
        z-index:3;
        padding:15px;

    }


    #titre {

        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "fr">
    <html>


        <head>
            <meta charset= "UTF-8" />
            <title> Connexion </title>
            <link href="connexion.css" rel="stylesheet">

        </head>



        <body>

        <header> 

            <h1>Portail informations des jeux olympiques</h1>


            <a href = "https://www.paris2024.org/fr/" target="_blank"> <img src = "jo.png" height = 30% width = 7% alt = "Logo JO" /> </a>
        </header>


        <nav>

            <a href = "https://www.paris2024.org/fr/"> Accueil </a>
            <a href = "https://www.paris2024.org/fr/sports-olympiques/"> Programme </a>
            <a href = "https://tickets.paris2024.org/">Billeterie </a>
            <a href = "https://www.paris2024.org/fr/ceremonie/">Evenement </a>
            
        
        </nav>


        <div id = "Contour"></div>

            <main id ="Contour2">  
            <div id = "Contour2"></div>
            <div id = "Contour3"></div>




            <h2 id = "titre"> Connexion </h2>


        </main>


        <footer>
            @ 2023 Portails Informations 

        </footer>


        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning seems like a *really bad* choice to achieve that layout. Please [MDN's guide to CSS layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout) for some **much** better alternatives.

Comment: I'll second that, find a way to keep things in flow, *do not use* position:absolute unless you understand the consequences

Comment: Okay thank you guys, i dont have to use the position:absolute like this, I'm going to do it another way